# How to disappear one of link of navigation?

Tags: css, hyperlink

Please help me to make one of this link of navigation disappear in this page by CSS
my code

```
<body id="quiz">
<div class="container">
  <header> 

    <div > 
      <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.xhtml" id="indexnav">Home</a></li>
          <li class="has-sub"> <a href="#" id="topicnav">Topic</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="html5intro.xhtml"><span>HTML5</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="inputElement.xhtml"><span>Input Type</span></a></li>
              <li class='last'><a href="inputMore.xhtml"><span>More Input Atributes</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="liregister"> <a href="register.xhtml" id="registernav">Register</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="about.xhtml" id="aboutnav">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="enhancement.xhtml" id="enhancementnav">Enhancement</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

Question is how to disappear link "Register"?
Thank you

Comment: Please post your HTML code, at least.

Comment: display:none is what you are looking for. Please post a fiddle though from the next time so that people understand your code and know that you made an attempt

Answer (score 0):

```
#registernav {
display:none;
}
```

Put this in your css

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the link then

```
#registernav {
display:none;
}
```

However, this will still leave the list item visible (even if the link is no longer there).

To hide the while list item you would need

```
.liregister {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, `display:none` hides an element, and it will not take up any space. The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there:

```css
.liregister {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body id="quiz">
  <div class="container">
    <header>

      <div>
        <nav class="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.xhtml" id="indexnav">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub"> <a href="#" id="topicnav">Topic</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="html5intro.xhtml"><span>HTML5</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="inputElement.xhtml"><span>Input Type</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class='last'><a href="inputMore.xhtml"><span>More Input Atributes</span></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="liregister"> <a href="register.xhtml" id="registernav">Register</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="about.xhtml" id="aboutnav">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="enhancement.xhtml" id="enhancementnav">Enhancement</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

**OR**

you could delete the list item itself from the page.

```html
<body id="quiz">
  <div class="container">
    <header>

      <div>
        <nav class="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.xhtml" id="indexnav">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub"> <a href="#" id="topicnav">Topic</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="html5intro.xhtml"><span>HTML5</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="inputElement.xhtml"><span>Input Type</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class='last'><a href="inputMore.xhtml"><span>More Input Atributes</span></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="about.xhtml" id="aboutnav">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="enhancement.xhtml" id="enhancementnav">Enhancement</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
</body>
```